# uvicorn error on AWS EC2 with uvicorn + fastapi

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a server running locally. When I run it on AWS EC2 and send a request from outside on port 8000, I get the following error:

```
$ uvicorn sql_app.main:app --host="0.0.0.0" --port=8000
INFO:     Started server process [9806]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
WARNING:  Invalid HTTP request received.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 170, in handle_events
    event = self.conn.next_event()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h11/_connection.py", line 443, in next_event
    exc._reraise_as_remote_protocol_error()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h11/_util.py", line 76, in _reraise_as_remote_protocol_error
    raise self
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h11/_connection.py", line 425, in next_event
    event = self._extract_next_receive_event()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h11/_connection.py", line 367, in _extract_next_receive_event
    event = self._reader(self._receive_buffer)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h11/_readers.py", line 73, in maybe_read_from_IDLE_client
    request_line_re, lines[0], "illegal request line: {!r}", lines[0]
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h11/_util.py", line 88, in validate
    raise LocalProtocolError(msg)
h11._util.RemoteProtocolError: illegal request line: bytearray(b'\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xfc\x03\x03\x91\xa5\xe2Y\xf0\xa1\xdd\x1d+\x08\x1c\r\x15X\x1d@\x1e/\xb1N\x00\xb5\xe5\xec\xf3F\x1fm\x03\xa1{> \xa80\xb4\x14\x1aUs\xaa\xcd\xc3<s\xcd\xd1\x17\xdf3\x0e\xdbh\xd1c\x88}\x8c\x1f\xa5\x15\x9aa\x14I\x00 ')
WARNING:  Invalid HTTP request received.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 170, in handle_events
    event = self.conn.next_event()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h11/_connection.py", line 443, in next_event
    exc._reraise_as_remote_protocol_error()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h11/_util.py", line 76, in _reraise_as_remote_protocol_error
    raise self
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h11/_connection.py", line 425, in next_event
    event = self._extract_next_receive_event()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h11/_connection.py", line 367, in _extract_next_receive_event
    event = self._reader(self._receive_buffer)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h11/_readers.py", line 68, in maybe_read_from_IDLE_client
    raise LocalProtocolError("illegal request line")
h11._util.RemoteProtocolError: illegal request line
WARNING:  Invalid HTTP request received.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 170, in handle_events
    event = self.conn.next_event()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h11/_connection.py", line 443, in next_event
    exc._reraise_as_remote_protocol_error()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h11/_util.py", line 76, in _reraise_as_remote_protocol_error
    raise self
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h11/_connection.py", line 425, in next_event
    event = self._extract_next_receive_event()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h11/_connection.py", line 367, in _extract_next_receive_event
    event = self._reader(self._receive_buffer)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h11/_readers.py", line 68, in maybe_read_from_IDLE_client
    raise LocalProtocolError("illegal request line")
h11._util.RemoteProtocolError: illegal request line
WARNING:  Invalid HTTP request received.
```

It would be very nice if you could tell me how to do it on port 80.

Comment: ```
raise LocalProtocolError(msg)
h11._util.RemoteProtocolError: illegal request line: bytearray(b'\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xfc\x03\x03\x18\xc6\x16Xm\x87\x96`\xff\x97\xd4\x86\xa6d\x8b\x0e\xc0\xb3Dwh\xc0\xd7K\x90\xcfj\x1e\x1fr\xe1\xfe \x15\xa0\xbd\xda\x8f\xc5~\xbd\x16\x11\xc2\xbd\x8b\x9a\x06\xe5P\xab\x8a\xff\xc8\xc0\xe3m\x10\xecOU\x91_U\x8f\x00"\x9a\x9a\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xc0+\xc0/\xc0,\xc00\xcc\xa9\xcc\xa8\xc0\x13\xc0\x14\x00\x9c\x00\x9d\x00/\x005\x00')
```

Answer (score 26):

I was getting the same arcane `WARNING:  Invalid HTTP request received.` error with an unhelpful stack trace. I tried all of the environment variable tweaks recommended and none worked (see [FastAPI issue #680](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/680#issuecomment-621365894), [uvicorn issue #441](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/441#issuecomment-610542388)).

My issue was that when I was calling my FastAPI microservice I was using `https` when my microservice did not have HTTPS support. I changed the url from `https` to `http` and it started working as expected.

Note that if your service requires HTTPS support you can [add HTTPS support](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/https/?h=https) as Ilgizar Murzakov suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding HTTPS support. I configured NGINX with LetsEncrypt certificate. Make sure that the ports that you use are open at your security group settings.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Disabling http2 on application load balancer helped me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30964999)

Answer (score 0):

this is because uvicorn updated to display detailed error. [uvicorn #886](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/pull/886)

then, use uvicorn 0.13.1 which is before the update. this version won't display the error.

P.S: this update is to fix [this error](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/344). and uvicorn haven't fixed the error for now. [uvicorn #1296](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/1296)