# Invalid HTTP method in Traceback: Uvicorn

Tags: python, digital-ocean, fastapi, linode, uvicorn

I am using uvicorn 0.11.8 and fastapi 0.61.1. My application is hosted in  VPS. When I run the app in local server, such error is not reproducible. It shows correct message  404 Not found for methods not available but I couldn't figure out what is causing this issue in VPS (error in Traceback).
[image]

Comment: Happened with me in `httpS://localhost:8000` instead of `http`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was getting the same arcane `WARNING:  Invalid HTTP request received.` error with an unhelpful stack trace. I tried all of the environment variable tweaks recommended and none worked (see [FastAPI issue #680](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/680#issuecomment-621365894), [uvicorn issue #441](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/441#issuecomment-610542388)).

My issue was that when I was calling my FastAPI microservice I was using `https` when my microservice did not have HTTPS support. I changed the url from `https` to `http` and it started working as expected.

Note that if your service requires HTTPS support you can [add HTTPS support](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/https/?h=https).

Also, see the similar post [AWS ec2 + uvicorn + fastapi, i get uvicorn error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65603806/aws-ec2-uvicorn-fastapi-i-get-uvicorn-error).

Comment: I came here during similar search, and my issue was that I created a `Celery` client which was trying to connect to the `RabbitMQ` constantly, and all the requests were forwarded to `FastAPI` via `rpc` or `amqp` protocols`, which leads to error above